# Find the index of the first day of the year (new year)

Tags: java

I'm a novice programmer who's trying to make a calendar (part of the homework). I've finished everything else but got stuck on the part where I'm finding the index of the New Year (from 0 - 6) which shifts to the right by one every year except for the year after leap year which shifts by two. I don't have a good algorithm for this particular part so I just thought about it off the top of my head. It computes and works up to 1800 but after that it doesn't work properly anymore. I have no idea why. But here's the code:

public static int indexOfNewYear (int month, int year){

```
    int count = 0;
    int modOfDays = 0;
    int numberOfDays = 365;

    year = year - 2; // starts with year 2 because index of New Year is 0

    for (int t = 1; t <= year; year--){

        if(year + 2 == 1753){ // year 1752 skipped 11 days ahead
            numberOfDays += 10;
        } 

        count = modOfDays + numberOfDays;
        modOfDays = count  % 7;     

        if((year + 1) %  4 == 0 && year != 1){ // leap year skips two indexes
            modOfDays += 1;
        }
    }

    //System.out.println("modOfDays: " + modOfDays);
    return modOfDays;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You know your leap year test is not completely correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm

Comment: It's unusual to intialise a variable in a `for` loop that you don't subsequently change the value of. `for (int t = 1; ...)` -> t is always 1.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at how you're computing the leap year - if you're using the Gregorian Calendar leap years only occur on years divisible by 4 EXCEPT years divisible by 100 UNLESS the year is also divisible by 400.

So, 1900 (divisible by 100 but not by 400) is a common year , whereas 2000 (divisible by 100 and by 400) is a leap year.

Work this logic into how you're computing the leap year.